# Okular and other applications open HTML Links in wrong application

Tags: default-programs

There are some applications that open html links in gvim instead of Firefox.

HTML Documents are linked to Firefox though, as I verified with the Tweak-Tool. Also, if I safe the html file somewhere and open that file, it is opened in Firefox.

What might be the reason for that?

Comment: Does `xdg-open http://google.com` opens google in the wrong application?

Comment: What Desktop environment are you using? If you are using KDE Tweak Tool will not work probably.

Comment: `xdg-open http://google.com` opens correctly in Firefox.

Comment: @Kuntal Majumder: I use Unity.

Comment: I still have the problem. x-www-browser http://google.com  works correctly as well. For example right-click on dropbox -> view on dropbox.com does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Old post, but if someone also have this problem, as I also encountered this problem, here is a solution I found to solve this problem with Okular (and may be other apps if using KDE as desktop environment).

If you are using KDE, open **Configuration panel** -> **Applications** -> **File association**

Search for "http", then in "inode", select "vnd.kde.service.http".
Add Firefox in applications (or other browser) and set it as first application (if other).

You'll probably have to quit Okular if it's running (or restart session).

*Note* : Some indications may be different, because my interface is not in English.